# Size of Widget Image

Tags: android

I have an image that I do not want to scale, I am using fitStart.  What size do I need to make it to ensure that it covers a 4x2 widget? I currently have an image that is 1024x768 and it doesn't cover.

UPDATE:
Here is the xml and screen shot:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget_bg_rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/current_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:weightSum="8">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/city_time_rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_top">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/city" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="MECHANICSBURG"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/dk_blue"
                />
```

[image]

Comment: 1024x768 is more pixels than most Android devices today.. that doesn't make sense. the widget size changes according to the screen dpi. 4x2 is 250dp on 110dp. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `fitStart`, which maintains the image aspect ratio, and ensures that one dimension (height, in this case) fits exactly.  It sounds like you want one of these two:

- If you want to fill the space, showing the entire image (and stretching it as necessary), use `fitXY`.
- If you want to fill the space, maintaining the image's aspect ratio (and cropping it as necessary), use `centerCrop`.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is to have the image large enough that it always fills the space, but if too large it simple doesn't show that portion.  What I have run into in the past is that Android devices have different grids (4x4, 5x5...etc) depending on the device and my images have been stretch/out of proportion. This has happened using fitXY.

Comment: @taraloca `centerCrop` it is, then.  That's exactly what it does.